# How to change the background color on hover for a Monaco editor delta decoration?

Tags: javascript, html, css, monaco-editor

Looking at the playground example, I can create and apply delta decorations just fine:

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "var a = true",
    language: "javascript"
});

var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([], [
    { range: new monaco.Range(3,1,5,1), options: { isWholeLine: true, linesDecorationsClassName: 'myLineDecoration' }},
    { range: new monaco.Range(7,1,7,24), options: { inlineClassName: 'myInlineDecoration' }},
]);
```

[image: monaco decorations applied]

However, the `:hover` variants of the css aren't respected at all for the decoration `className` at all.

The `:hover` variant for `inlineClassName` is respected, but only for the specific block I hover over, not the entire decoration:

[image: inlineClassName hover on specific block instead of the whole decoration]

I know Monaco's dom manipulation is very complex (and it's amazing it works in the browser so well!) so this may be expected.

Is there some way to affect the `:hover` background color of a Monaco editor delta decoration?

Comment: @Sysix The images are to show the result, not to show code (which is already there). Your comment is not relevant to this post.

Comment: can you please share a link to the playground or a playground with full code samples?

Comment: The screenshots show considerable more code than `var a = true`. Please expand to the minimal editor contents that can show this behaviour. And provide the css.